# Group by entities using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have entities like this

```
class Test
    {
        string Name;
        IList<SubTest> subTest;
    }

class SubTest
{
    string Id;
    string value;
}
```

from a server I will get result of `IEnumerable<Test>`.
I want ot convert this result to [SelectListItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx) so that I can bind this to mvc dropdown list.

Something like this

```
new SelectListItem(){Group=Test.Name, Value=SubTest.Id, Text= subTest.Value}
```

How can I get this result using linq?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Select()` and `SelectMany()` to transform the data into `SelectListItem`

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Test> lResultFromServer = ...;

var lSelectListItems = lResultFromServer.SelectMany(s =>
  s.subTest.Select(st => new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem {
    Group = new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListGroup {Name = s.Name},
    Value = st.Id,
    Text = st.value
  })
);
```

Comment: The properties of both Test and SubTest classes have to be set to public as well, so that they can be accessed

Comment: How I get the same result If the get the same object in javascript?

Comment: @PSR Javascript? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to get array/list with GroupName, Id, Value so that I can bind them to dropdown with group feature.

Comment: @PSR But Javascript is client side and your question was targeting LINQ, which is C#, which is server side. You can however output a javascript array from `lSelectListItems` by using a simple for each loop.